# DateTime formatting and timezone

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, format

When trying to parse a Date with `DateTime::createFromFormat` PHP will not recognize the timezone.

Example:

```
$t = new \DateTime(); 
echo $t->format('Y-m-dTH:i:s');
```

will output

```
2012-01-24MSK16:53:52
```

Now when I try to parse that string from the same format

```
var_dump(\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-dTH:i:s', '2012-01-24MSK16:53:52'));
```

I get

```
bool(false)
```

When I do not put the Timezone into the string, it works

```
$t = new \DateTime(); 
echo $t->format('Y-m-dH:i:s');
```

will give

```
2012-01-2417:17:24
```

and parsing that

```
var_dump(\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-dH:i:s', "2012-01-2417:17:24"));
```

will give

```
object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2012-01-24 17:17:24"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Moscow"
}
```

Tested on

- PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.3 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Dec 13 2011 18:18:37) and
- PHP 5.3.9 (cli) (built: Jan 18 2012 20:02:33)

Problem appears just if we are take care about timezone. Is it a bug? Or what I do wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I supposed to see:

php > $t = new \DateTime(); echo $t->format('Y-m-dH:i:s');
2012-01-2417:17:24
php > var_dump(\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-dH:i:s', "2012-01-2417:17:24"));
object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2012-01-24 17:17:24"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Moscow"
}

Comment: i know an answer, but:        

Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Comment: Gordon, very thank you for edit!!! Just followed you on twitter =)

Comment: What kind of format is `Y-m-dTH:i:s` anyway; were you instead wanting `Y-m-d\TH:i:s`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like a bug (or at least an *undocumented limitation*) with PHP...  If we try the 4 possible whitespace permutations:

```
var_dump(\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-dTH:i:s', '2012-01-24MSK16:53:52'));
var_dump(\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d T H:i:s', '2012-01-24 MSK 16:53:52'));
var_dump(\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d TH:i:s', '2012-01-24 MSK16:53:52'));
var_dump(\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-dT H:i:s', '2012-01-24MSK 16:53:52'));
```

We get (tested PHP 5.3, 5.4rc6 and Trunk):

```
bool(false)
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2012-01-24 16:53:52"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(2)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "MSK"
}
bool(false)
object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2012-01-24 16:53:52"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(2)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "MSK"
}
```

So that seems to point that the timezone identifier and/or hour are sensitive to whitespace...  Testing further:

```
var_dump(\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2012-01-24 16:53:52'));
var_dump(\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-dH:i:s', '2012-01-2416:53:52'));
```

Yields the proper results.  And:

```
var_dump(\DateTime::createFromFormat('TY-m-d', 'MSK2012-01-24'));
var_dump(\DateTime::createFromFormat('T Y-m-d', 'MSK 2012-01-24'));
```

Yields:

```
bool(false)
object(DateTime)#4 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2012-01-24 01:49:26"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(2)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "MSK"
}
```

So yes, it does appear that the timezone specifier is sensitive to trailing whitespace...

### Edit: It is white-space sensitive

If we look at [parse_date.c `timelib_parse_from_format()` on line 25075](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/date/lib/parse_date.c#25075), we can see that all 4 timezone formats are parsed the same way!  That means there is no difference at all between the format identifiers for parsing, and therefore **for parsing** they are interchangable.

That alone seems like enough of a bug (or lack of a feature) to go on.  But, let's see what happens in [`timelib_get_zone()`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/date/lib/parse_date.c#timelib_get_zone) which is called when you use a timezone identifier.  Well, looking on, we can see that we call [`timelib_lookup_zone()`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/date/lib/parse_date.c#timelib_lookup_zone) when it's not GMT or a time offset.

And there we found the bug.  On line 768 of `timelib_lookup_zone`, we can see that it will consume the entire input string up to one of either `\0` (null), `)` or a space:

```
while (**ptr != '\0' && **ptr != ')' && **ptr != ' ') {
    ++*ptr;
}
```

With respect to fixing it, that's a little more tricky.  To just fix this issue, would require re-implementing the format parsers for each timezone.  For the `T` parser, this is easy, since it's always a 3 letter string.  But for the others, it's a little more interesting, since there are variable letters, and as such whitespace sensitivity may be an issue.

So in short, I would suggest just adding a trailing white-space to your timezone identifiers and being done with it...

Comment: FWIW, `T` isn't always a three letter string. It can be `CEST` for example as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if your php.ini has a default date.timezone and if not use [date_default_timezone_set](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) as DateTime relies on it.

Comment: judging by the output of the second example he already has a default timezone set. And I doubt this has anything to do with it anyway

Comment: right answer is:


To create a \DateTime object from format with timezone, you need to separate time and timezone  by space.
php > var_dump(\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-dH:i:s T', "2012-01-2417:15:59 MSK"));
object(DateTime)#16 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2012-01-24 17:15:59"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(2)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "MSK"
}

OR

php > var_dump(\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d T H:i:s', "2012-01-24 MSK 17:15:59"));
object(DateTime)#21 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2012-01-24 17:15:59"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(2)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "MSK"
}

Comment: but I can't make it as answer, because:

but: Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because: Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.